# Inferring types in a function arg from values at call site fails when there are multiple generics

Tags: typescript

In a function, I want to infer the type of an arg using generics and the runtime values passed.

It seems to work in a simple case, but fails when multiple generics are involved.

Here's my code demonstrating the issue:

[Typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DDtGyuOvMGulHrrd7hhHs9U+9PgBqX7-aRAsB0QSRhiEIFcmVoFk2S3eZiEWEEmUrJhyBAwhGErRFkUcIA)

```
// this simple case works

function fn1 <Arg> (args: {
  provideType: () => Arg,
  consumeType: (arg: Arg) => void
}): void {
  const one = args.provideType()

  args.consumeType(one)
}

fn1({ 
  provideType: () => ({ foo: 1, bar: 2 }), // type of arg provided at call site
  consumeType: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.foo * arg.bar) // arg has expected type
  }
})

// but using multiple generics like this fails

function fn2 <T, Arg> (args: { // extra generic T, passed as an arg to provider in same way
  thing: T,
  provideType: (thing: T) => Arg,
  consumeType: (arg: Arg) => void
}):void {
  const one = args.provideType(args.thing)

  args.consumeType(one)
}

fn2 ({ 
  thing: 'hello', // give a value to T at call site
  provideType: (t) => ({ foo: t, bar: 2 }), // this works, t resolved as 'string' type
  consumeType: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.foo + arg.bar) // but now this fails, type of arg is 'unknown'
  }
})
```

Why does the second case not work?

The goal is to define an interface for a function with several functions passed as arguments where the return value from each one, once implemented, can then be used in all subsequent functions with the types automatically inferred.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what "runtime" means in this question.  Everything you're talking about here is happening in the type checker, during compilation.  Runtime is much later, when the compiled JavaScript script actually runs.  Perhaps you mean "call site" or something instead of runtime? Not sure.

Comment: Good point, I'm trying to refer to the runtime of the compiler, but there's too much overload with the usual meaning of runtime for that to be a good term! Will switch this with 'call site'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript's type inference algoritm; see [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for a canonical answer.

---

In the following call,

```
fn2({
  thing: 'hello',
  provideType: (t) => ({ foo: t, bar: 2 }),
  consumeType: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.foo + arg.bar) // error!
  }
})
```

the callbacks you give for `provideType` and `consumeType` need their parameters, `t` and `arg` to be [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) in order for this to succeed.  So instead of being able to read types *from* `t` and `arg`, the compiler needs to assign types *to* them.  Meanwhile it also needs to infer the `T` and `Arg` generic type parameters at the same time.

The way the compiler tries to do this is to infer everything in two phases:

In the first phase, all the callback parameters in need of contextual types are given placeholder "wildcard" types, and the compiler tries to infer just the generic type parameters from this.  This means cannot infer anything from `provideType` or `consumeType` yet, but it does infer `string` for `T`, because that's the type of `thing`.  For `Arg`, it has no idea, because it would need information from at least the return type of `provideType`, but it has deferred evaluating that.  And so inference fails for `Arg`, and the compiler falls back to `unknown`.

In the second phase, the compiler uses those generic type parameters to give types to the callback parameters.  And so `t` is inferred to be a `string` (hooray) and `arg` is inferred to be `unknown` (boo).

And that's it, there's no more type inference here. It's a design limitation.  To quote the [relevant comment on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872#issuecomment-651450956):

> In order to support this particular scenario we'd need additional inference phases, i.e. one per contextually sensitive property value, similar to what we do for multiple contextually sensitive parameters. Not clear that we want to venture there, and it would still be sensitive to the order in which object literal members are written. Ultimately there are limits to what we can do without full unification in type inference.

---

So, what can you do instead?  The obvious but unsatisfying workarounds would be either to manually specify the type parameters (so that only contextual typing is needed):

```
fn2<string, { foo: string, bar: number }>({  // <-- specify 
  thing: 'hello',
  provideType: (t) => ({ foo: t, bar: 2 }),
  consumeType: (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.foo + arg.bar) // okay
  }
})
```

or to manually annotate the offending callback parameter (so that only generic type parameter inference is needed):

```
fn2({
  thing: 'hello',
  provideType: (t) => ({ foo: t, bar: 2 }),
  consumeType: (arg: { foo: string, bar: number }) => { // <-- annotate
    console.log(arg.foo + arg.bar) // okay
  }
})
```

Another idea is to refactor your function so that the type inference algorithm doesn't have to do everything "at once".  The compiler is better about inferring types from multiple different function arguments than it is doing so from a single object... especially if the types can be inferred by considering the arguments from left to right.  So you might consider splitting the `args` object into three separate parameters, like this:

```
function fn3<T, Arg>(
  thing: T,
  provideType: (thing: T) => Arg,
  consumeType: (arg: Arg) => void
): void {
  const one = provideType(thing)
  consumeType(one)
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
fn3(
  'hello',
  (t) => ({ foo: t, bar: 2 }),
  (arg) => {
    console.log(arg.foo + arg.bar) // okay
  }
);
```

Now everything works; `T` is inferred as `string`, and `Arg` is inferred as `{foo: string; bar: number}`.  It might not be the form you wanted, but at least you are not requiring that the caller specify redundant type information.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-aeMcQ5nO6TjjpO9ypDO6rzohS6CmAxDkCaW5hDQdB5gWShPqW5aVsQ1bWistrgWIjZDs2vR-gBQHdiBnr1g8-LHrIp4HsxV43neYRQQ4MGXNctwIcISGgCh0loTMmHYUoMK4bUzKsOwnCMAAzJy3LCOIhYHpa75UXGhj2kWjoys6Ng9vsfaWRB3gukI-ohlQ4QBCGw6jhGhJRh+mZJmxYGVIS1QwrmOliA4L5kRRSi0d+3FtsMl4TMByWQf40GjnBknTi2skLgpGFYaaKleQA3DQwDvAwzCaWyum8Lx55+Uov4IPuaJ1SOHYCUgt6kHVITiMRHWHsFNFTX17kiSOPXTQN5xDdeI1EuNgy9p+nFdWlq2iRlgHDaN40eVo3kBm8wBUEAA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, it's good to know why this doesn't work and I think I'll go with the 'non named arguments' refactor as a workaround.